# Is it safe to remove a usb hard drive while it is spinning?

Tags: external-hard-drive

I have used safely remove function in windows, but my hard drive is still spinning sometimes even with clicking sound, is it safe to remove it? (my usb hard drive is toshiba v73600-H)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is 'safe' to unplug the hard disk drive while still spinning; as there are safety mechanisms in place with modern hard disk drives to allow for quick removal. In the *old days* you used to have to 'park' a disk before removing power, else the platters would be destroyed, but I am not even old enough to remember those days. :)